# Collect custom post in a calendar

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery, ajax, metabox, post-meta

I'm working on a site in which I have incorporated a calendar of events, which also serves as navigation in the events page. That is to say that when I click on a calendar date associated events occur. To do this I integrate the plugin [jQuery.Simple-Event-Calendar](https://github.com/philipehsing/jQuery.Simple-Event-Calendar), this plugin uses a jquery json file to load events. My problem is that I can not retrieve my calendar events with good dates. Would anyone have any idea how I could do to recover my posts good dates via json or via the query wordpress?

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: What do you mean by `good dates`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing piece to this is; where does your data currently live? If you have an endpoint for the JSON then parsing via jQuery is pretty straightforward.

```
<script>
    jQuery.getJSON ({
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/philipehsing/jQuery.Simple-Event-Calendar/master/demo/data/events.json',
    })
    .done (function(data) {
        for (var i in data.events) {
            var event = data.events[i];
            var date = event.month + "/" + event.day + "/" + event.year;
            console.log (event.title + " is on " + date);
        }
    })
</script>
```